# Multiple run time errors on querying records with EF using contains

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm writing an update method utilizing EF-5 and having problems selecting records to do a targeted update.

```
public void Update(List<MyEntities> entitiesToUpdate)
{
    // Get rows that match IDs
    var findUpdateRows = this
        ._context
        .MyEntity
        .Where(w => entitiesToUpdate
            .Select(s => s.SomePropertyId)
            .ToList()
            .Contains(w.SomePropertyId)
        )
        .ToList();
}

    // run time error - LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] ToList[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

If I instead try:

```
    // Get rows that match IDs
    var findUpdateRows = this
        ._context
        .MyEntity
        .Where(w => entitiesToUpdate
            .Select(s => s.SomePropertyId)
            .Contains(w.SomePropertyId)
        )
        .ToList();

    // Run time error - Unable to create a constant value of type 'xxx.MyEntities'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

I can get the method to work as expected when using the below (but I'd like to know and understand how to accomplish the same without having the separate idsToUpdate var and assignment):

```
    // Create list of IDs to update
    List<int> idsToUpdate = new List<int>();
    entitiesToUpdate.ForEach(fe => idsToUpdate.Add(fe.SomePropertyId));

    // Get rows that match IDs
    var findUpdateRows = this
        ._context
        .MyEntity
        .Where(w => idsToUpdate.Contains(w.SomePropertyId))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: look up how to use `Any()` in stead of `Contains`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception

> Unable to create a constant value of type ...

always indicates that somewhere in the LINQ statement objects (class instances) are used where EF can only handle primitive values. So the first step is to look: where do I use objects?

```
var findUpdateRows = this._context.MyEntity // here
                         .Where(w => entitiesToUpdate // here
                                     .Select(s => s.SomePropertyId)
                                     .Contains(w.SomePropertyId))
```

Now we know that just the line `this._context.MyEntity` will run, so it should be `entitiesToUpdate`. Which you intuitively figured out.

The reason is that the whole expression (`entitiesToUpdate` is an `Expression`) is translated into SQL and EF simply has no way to translate a `List` of (class) objects into SQL (just try to imagine what it should look like in SQL :/).

So you did the right thing, although

```
var idsToUpdate = entitiesToUpdate.Select(s => s.SomePropertyId).ToList();
```

is a bit shorter.

Comment: interesting.  I would have though that <code>entitiesToUpdate
            .Select(s => s.SomePropertyId)
            .ToList()
            .Contains(w.SomePropertyId)</code> and var <code>idsToUpdate....</code> would pretty much equate to the same thing.  Oh well thanks for the input :)

Comment: Er... how do i do code tags in comments without the rich text editor? I tried both ' and <code> :O

Comment: I think it's impossible to decide for EF what to evaluate in memory and what to translate into SQL. So it tries to translate everything into SQL. For `ToList()` there's no SQL equivalent and when there is a List/IEnumerable in the LINQ statement it can only be translated into SQL if it's unambiguous how the items can be converted into constants (e.g. for an `IN` clause).